# GKE Internal Server error

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm new to the concept of containers and cloud. I was following through this [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cp100-container-engine/). I've followed along very carefully to the last step but when I try to launch the app in the web browser, I receive this error:[Internal Server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPTJh.png). Everything looks fine to me. The pods are running.

```
>NAME                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
bookshelf-frontend-dv72k   1/1       Running   0          46s
bookshelf-frontend-pjlx5   1/1       Running   0          46s
bookshelf-frontend-xdbm7   1/1       Running   0          46s
```

And so are the services:

```
NAME                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        AGE
bookshelf-frontend   LoadBalancer   10.11.240.22   35.188.5.106   80:30322/TCP   6m
kubernetes           ClusterIP      10.11.240.1    <none>         443/TCP        22m
```

The redirection is successful because as I run `curl -L 35.188.5.106`, it outputs to the same error. The DNS can resolve to the home page.

I've even tried following along this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/) but it seemed pretty confusing. I was still able to check most of the suggestions in there except for the one that involved running commands on pods. The service is correct, kube-proxy is running, the service has it's endpoints. I have no clue how to proceed further.

I could have provided logs but did not know which ones to look for. Please help.

Edit: I've used the app and was able to perfectly set it up on the app-engine and the compute-engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I followed the same process except that I changed the zone to a more local one. Previously my configuration was set to use the us-central1-a zone which I changed to an Asian one(I'm in India). That apparently seemed to have solved the issue.